# How can I have a fallback run-time implementation in a constexpr function

Tags: c++, constexpr, fallback

## Context

I'm making a math library and I need to use `sqrt()`.
As `sqrt()` is not a `constexpr` function I've implemented a `constexpr` version of `sqrt()` and a faster that `std::sqrt()` that uses assembly, so must be used on run-time.
Now, I'm using all this to calculate the length of a vector, and this function can be `constexpr` because I'm making `constexpr` everything possible in the struct.

```
constexpr inline Real length() const { return const_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared());}
```

This will work, if the `lenght()` function is called in a non `constexpr` context, it simply run in run-time, but I have a faster run-time implementation of `sqrt()` than `const_sqrt()`.

## Question

How can I switch to use one implementation or another based on if the function is executed on compile-time or run-time.
Something like this:

```
constexpr inline Real length() const { 
    return IN_RUN_TIME 
         ? fast_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared()) 
         : const_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only standard-compliant solution is to use [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated), as [suggested by cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62609853/2752075):

```
constexpr inline Real length() const
{ 
    return std::is_constant_evaluated()
         ? fast_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared()) 
         : const_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared());
}
```

The problem with this approach is that `std::is_constant_evaluated()` will only return `true` if the return value of `length()` is used to initialize a `constexpr` variable, or is otherwise *required* to be `constexpr`.

This is suboptimal in situations where the value of `lengthSquared()` is known at compile-time (thus `const_sqrt` **could** be used), but the return value of `length()` is not required to be `constexpr`. Then `is_constant_evaluated` will return `false`, so `fast_sqrt` is going to be used instead, unnecessarily postponing<sup>1</sup> the computation to runtime.

The workaround for that is to use a non-standard GCC built-in (also supported by Clang): [`__builtin_constant_p`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). Unlike `std::is_constant_evaluated`, it has an 'expression' parameter and checks if the value of the expression is known at compile-time (which might depend on optimization settings).

I suggest that `__builtin_constant_p` should be used if it's available, falling back to `std::is_constant_evaluated` otherwise. (And if you're using a pre-C++20 compiler, this built-in is your only option.)

```
#ifdef __GNUC__ // Defined by GCC and Clang
#define KNOWN_AT_COMPILE_TIME(...) __builtin_constant_p(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define KNOWN_AT_COMPILE_TIME(...) std::is_constant_evaluated()
#endif

constexpr inline Real length() const
{ 
    return KNOWN_AT_COMPILE_TIME(lengthSquared())
         ? fast_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared()) 
         : const_sqrt<Real>(lengthSquared());
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume `fast_sqrt` doesn't work at compile-time. Otherwise there's no point in having a separate `const_sqrt`.

Answer (score 3):

In c++20, the function [`std::is_constant_evaluated`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constant_evaluated) can be used for this purpose:

```
constexpr Real length() const { 
    return ! std::is_constant_evaluated()
         ? fast_sqrt(lengthSquared()) 
         : const_sqrt(lengthSquared());
}
```

As far as I'm aware, pre-c++20, there was no way to achieve this effect, which is why it was added to the language.

Also, note that `constexpr` implies `inline` so that keyword is redundant here.

Comment: I'm not sure about this one. Even with `-O3`, it appears to return `false` if the return value of `length` is used in a context that doesn't require `constexpr`ness, even when the return value of `lengthSquared()` can be computed at compile-time. I'd probably use `__builtin_constant_p(lengthSquared())` if it's available, it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Actually, I don't think optimization level has anything to do with how `is_constant_evaluated` is computed. It's strictly a language construct. Could you show the example you're referring to where you expect it to be `true`?

Comment: Yep, and I think it's a problem. Here's a small example: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/t6Br8J With this approach, you're always going to call `fast_sqrt` (unless the return value of `length` is used to initialize a constexpr variable, or otherwise required to be constexpr). That's not optimal if the value of `lengthSquared()` is known at compile-time, because it unnecessarily postpones the `sqrt` computation to runtime (I assume `fast_sqrt` can't be used at compile-time, otherwise a separate `const_sqrt` function wouldn't be necessary).

Comment: If you use it in a explicit `constexpr` context works perfect (prints 11) https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SdLA-g

Comment: @HolyBlackCat No, that's correct behavior. The call to `foo` is not *manifestly-constant-evaluated* (at least, I think that's the terminology :p). If you force it to be constant, you get the constant [version](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YEM3vz)

Comment: @cigien I understand that. I'm not saying the compiler behaves incorrectly, but rather that `std::is_constant_evaluated` is not the best solution in this case.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Aah, I see. Yes, there are probably other ways to optimize the run-time version. But I think this answer's the OP's question correctly.

Comment: @BetaCoder Yeah, it does the right thing in some of the cases, but not in all cases. If it was my code, I'd want the `const_sqrt` to be used whenever possible, not just when `constexpr` variables are involved.